# Should I use location.href or chrome.tabs.query with message sending to get the tab URL?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome extension which recognizes certain URL pattern and perform further DOM manipulation. The content script has to get the current URL and matches with the predefined list of URL patterns.

There are two ways I could think of achieving the goal:
The first one would be using location.href

manifest.json

```
...
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }
],
...
```

content.js

```
console.log(location.href);
```

This method works fine. However, across other similar questions on StackOverflow, they usually suggests using chrome.tabs and message sending from background script to content script as follow:

manifest.json

```
...
"background" : {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }
],
...
```

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    chrome.tabs.get(tab.id, function(tabInfo) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
            url: tabInfo.url
        }, function(response) {
        });
    })
});
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {        
    if (request.url) {                          
        console.log(request.url)
        sendResponse(true);       
    }
    return true;
});
```

Both methods can have the URL correctly. And for the background script, it requires extra memory to keep the background script running in background, compared with content script which is only injected when loading the page.

On the other hand, using background script has benefit as the background script is said to be privileged, it can execute privileged Chrome APIs like the chrome.tabs API.

So as far as I am not using any privileged APIs, should I use the location.href or is there any particular reason most developers suggest using the chrome.tabs and message sending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Advantages of a background page script:**

1. Complex checks using additional information from the [Tab object](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab) (N.B. add `"tabs"` permissions to access `url`, `title`, `favIconUrl`), whereas manifest.json-based injection is limited to URL [wildcards/globs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#matches).

   - [chrome.declarativeContent API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent) with `RequestContentScript` action is an example of advanced filtering, it injects the content script(s) based on URL checks and DOM content (only simple selectors as noted in the documentation).
   - [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) inside [chrome.tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) or [chrome.webNavigation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) or [chrome.browserAction.onClicked](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked) listener to inject the content script(s) only when needed.
2. Changing the toolbar icon or the browser context menu to reflect change of state; content scripts can't do that, the background page script can.
3. Accessing privileged API like most of chrome.*, extension's internal storage such as IndexedDB, WebSQL, HTML5 FileSystem, localStorage (the latter is not a good choice though as it's not available in a content script directly, moreover it's synchronous and thus blocks execution).

In all the above cases it makes sense to pass data to content script using messages if that data was used while checking the conditions or it's only available in the background script. Otherwise [chrome.storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) inside the content script is as good or could be even better readability-wise.

**"Backgroundless" content script is better when all these conditions are met:**

1. URLs to process can be set entirely with wildcards/globs or it really really must be `<all_urls>`
2. all required parameters are accessible via `chrome.storage` API or no parameters needed
3. no privileged chrome.* APIs are used as those [aren't available](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) in content scripts, in other words *when the background page is not actually needed*.

As for memory consumption: either method may be better or worse depending on how it's used.
If the content script is injected on all pages then each instance will consume memory (some people open 100 tabs so beware!). The worst case case is obviously when both persistent background page and content script on all URLs are used. Non-persistent event page might help but in a limited fashion because `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` is likely to run pretty frequently forcing the event page to reload (which also takes some time).